# Tool / utility for checking debugging XPath queries

Tags: windows, xpath

Has anyone got any recommendations for tools/utilities to use in creating/debugging XPath queries for Windows ?

Comment: hey microsoft has one with source code http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302300.aspx

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[SketchPath](http://qutoric.com/sketchpath/) looks like it might help (and is free)

Comment: Agreed.  Sketchpath is perfect for the job.  I just came across this piece of software about a week ago.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, well cool utility

Comment: it seems that the website is offline

Comment: @mishal153 - it's free again, but it's now integrated fully into an XML Editor app, so I've renamed it XMLQuire.

Comment: It's a useful tool, but sadly when handling large (10MB+) XML files, it really struggles and becomes unresponsive. The simple XPath expression evaluator in Notepad++ however handles it without issue.

Comment: @DanAtkinson I tried the online version with a 70MB XML file and it choked. Too bad.

Comment: @jcollum Have you tried Sublime Text? It has some nice XPath functionality.

Comment: @DanAtkinson I did not know that... how well does it work with large xml files?

Comment: @jcollum The biggest XML files I work with are 40MB. It handles them fine, although, so does Notepad++, so your mileage may vary...

Comment: All the XML plugins I can find for Notepad++ seem to choke when xpathing a file above 50MB.

Answer (score 20):

If you have Notepad++, there's an XML tools plugin. Among the tools in that plugin is a simple XPath expression evaluator. Sketchpatch is much more complete (I've tried it and it's nice) but if you use Notepad++ all the time it's worth knowing about this plugin.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/

Comment: notepad++ plugin is very very useful!!!

Comment: The "Select XPath" in this tool is completely broken. I can't get `/TraceData` to return any nodes, just says empty set.

Answer (score 13):

There is a new plugin for Notepad++: [XPatherizerNPP](http://code.google.com/p/xpatherizernpp/). The biggest advantage it has over XML Tools is the reverse lookup feature.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of good options on Codeplex ..

XPathVisualiser at http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/

XMLExplorer at http://xmlexplorer.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

Liquid XML Studio comes with an [XPath visualizer](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XmlStudio/XPath-Expression-Builder.aspx). The stand alone version is free in the community edition. If you want to integrate it into visual studio then you have to buy it though.

It highlights the results as you type, and has auto complete on the XPath expression.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [XmlSpy](http://www.altova.com/products/xmlspy/xmlspy.html).

Comment: Sorry, I should have said FREE ... can't afford XmlSpy for personal use