# What tool do you use for testing and developing XPath expressions?

Tags: .net, xpath

I'd like something similar to [Gerry Shaw's regex tool](http://organicbit.com/Posts/2002-01-Regex.html),

[image]

... but for XPath.
I'd prefer a standalone tool, free, built on .NET, WinForms or WPF.

---

**EDIT**:
I found [this one](http://www.codeplex.com/xpathtester) on codeplex, which fits my requirements as stated, but it's sort of feature-free.  It doesn't even resize.

[image]

Comment: For the same reason I need a tool to "Develop" regex - because the task is sufficiently complex enough that I'd like to be able to visualize which nodes I am selecting with various xpath expressions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a [free option](http://XPathVisualizer.codeplex.com).

If it looks interesting or useful to you, you can [download the source or binary for yourself](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you use Notepad++, there's a plugin for that called XML tools.
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

There's also [Sketchpath](http://www.sketchpath.com) which is more complete.

And this made me realize this is a duplicate of
 
[Tool / utility for checking debugging XPath queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801858/tool-utility-for-checking-debugging-xpath-queries/802300#802300)

Comment: It's actually 'SketchPath' at http://www.sketchpath.com, not 'SketchPatch'. A typo I'm sure, but just to clarify - its based on .NET 2.0/WinForms

Comment: Notepad++ has plugin called XPatherizerNPP which is quite cool.

Comment: @mishal153 cheers that seems much better than the one in xmltools - it just seemed to return gibberish characters when trying to run queries

Answer (score 1):

[oXygen XML](http://www.oxygenxml.com/)

Not free, but worth it if you do any serious XPath/XSLT development.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Xpath Checker](http://slesinsky.org/brian/code/xpath_checker.html) plugin for firefox.  Works quite nicely, but I wouldn't classify it as a "serious development tool".  But very handy for testing xpath expressions.

Comment: I use this, too. On Linux, however, the display of the matching results was unreadable. I had to hack the add-on's config file, increasing the "height" attribute of the text field size.